# SQL Query - Don't grab this unless this

Tags: sql

I'm modifying a query I have that pulls news items from my database. These news items have tags, which, in the database, is stored in a single column as a string separated by commas.

For example:

```
'content,video,featured video,foo'
```

What I'm trying to do is grab all the items in the table but **not** the items that contain `'video'` in the tags string, **unless** the tag string also contains `'featured video'`

What is the best way to do this?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
WHERE status = 2 
ORDER BY postDate
```

Comment: The _best_ way? Normalize the field into a `Tags` table and have a many-to-many link between posts and tags.

Comment: By the way, what RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm offering horrible thing, but if you want to stick to your table structure, you may try following:

```
 SELECT * FROM posts
    WHERE STATUS=2 AND
    INSTR(tags,'featured video')>0 
    OR
    INSTR(tags,'video')=0
```

At least use `FULLTEXT` index on that field, so it won't be this painful to use.

Comment: David, thank you very much! This works perfectly and is extremely efficient - just as efficient as the original query.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best way to do it...

```
Select *
FROM posts
where status = 2
AND postID NOT IN 
(SELECT postID FROM posts 
 WHERE tag LIKE '%Video%'
 AND tag NOT like '%Featured Video%')
```

I am assuming PostId to be the PK from the posts table btw...

Comment: +1 I like the understandability and maintainability of NOT IN, though performance can be an issue.

Comment: Andrew, this works just like I'd like but performance is an issue. It makes my query 5 times slower. Thank you, though! Made me understand it.

Comment: Yeah, if there's a lot of data it will have performance issues.  If the tab is going to be EXACTLY Video or Featured video then you can use an equals instead of Like and that will probably improve things....

Answer (score 1):

I would use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  posts 
WHERE
  status = 2
  AND (CONCAT(',', tags, ',') LIKE '%,featured video,%'
       OR CONCAT(',', tags, ',') NOT LIKE '%,video,%')
ORDER BY
  postDate
```